# podAffinity not working on Elastic Search(statefulset)

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I am trying to deploy elasticsearch using helm chart( elastic repo ) in my EKS with two nodes.
The charts deploys 3 replicas of pods using statefulsets .
But only two replicas are being able to run whereas the third one stuck in pending state.

Changing or removing the affinity/anti-affinity rules had no effects no far. Everytime the replica is being assigned to seperate nodes. I am not being able to run more than one replicas on single node.
I want to run multiples replicas in the available two nodes. I even tried upgrading my EKS resources just to be sure the resource is of no issue.

Comment: Is your EKS configured to autoscale? If your cluster only has two nodes and the ES deployment is trying to scale each of the nodes onto different nodes, it won't be able to schedule the third ES node without a third kubernetes node. You can describe the pending pod by doing `kubectl describe pod -n {namespace} {pending-pod}` and see what shows in the event log at the bottom of the output.

Comment: eks in not configured to autoscaling. 
- on describing pending nodes, i get the following message.
Warning  FailedScheduling  2m52s (x121 over 123m)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu.

however, if  i try to schedule the pods on a single node by adding podAffinity rule, it is not also working as expected. Each pod is looking to get scheduled on seperate node. It worked with the other deployments but the same do not works for ES.
Does the each replicas of statefulsets requires separate nodes to get scheduled ?

Thank you !!

Comment: That error `r 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu` indicates your kubernetes nodes don't have enough CPU capacity to handle running two ES worker pods on the same node. So your options are 1) increase to 3 kubernetes nodes; 2) reduce the requested CPU resource so each worker pod doesn't require so much CPU; 4) enable autoscaling so the cluster can scale up another node automatically.